# why am I get this error?: " ??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch

Tags: compiler-errors

why am I get this error?:

`" ???` Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

```
Error in ==> Untitled2 at 6 C(i,1) = B(67:74); "
```

**My code is:**

```
C = zeros(1230,1);
for i=1:1230
    B = A(i,1);
    B = char(B);
    C(i,1) = B(67:74);
end
```

A is a 1230*1 cell, which there is a text in every cells! I've also checked my code like this and it works!

```
for i=1:1230
    B = A(i,1);
    B = char(B);
    Z = B(67:74);
end
```

but I want to save All 1230 items in a matrix! Thanks

Comment: And we are doing which language?

Comment: Try printing various values (e.g. `B(67:74)` in your test), this should give some insight into why you can't assign one thing to another.